# Update Search Index on Entry create and update

Tags: entries, search, index, cli

I have a multiselect drop-down for age group and I have set "Use this field’s values as search keywords" check box  checked.
when I create a new entry or update existing entry . we are not able to search using this field value unless we run this CLI command "php craft resave/entries --update-search-index"
we don't want to run this command every time when someone create or update entry.
Is there a solution to update search index automatically when someone create or update entry.

Thanks,

Amar Chand Yadav

Answer (score 1):

This should actually happen automatically. After saving an entry a queue task is created which updates the search index.

You could verify if this also applies to other fields (especially text fields) and then file an issue at Craft‘s GitHub page. Maybe this is a bug for dropdowns only.